# How can i make python ignore the empty inputs?

Tags: python

I want to make python ignore the empty inputs and move to the next one. 
Example:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
if x == "":
    print(y + z)
elif y == "":
    print(x + z)
elif z == "":
    print(x + y)
elif x == "" and y == "":
    print(z)
elif x == "" and z == "":
    print(y)
elif y == "" and z == "":
    print(x)
```

As you can see, this takes quite some lines. How do i simplify this?

Comment: `x` is an `int` and will never be "". Generally, though, scrubbing input can take a lot of code. Its the number one place where badness is injected into your algorithm. Don't fear the typing if that's what it takes to get clean input.

Comment: Due to your singe checks on x, y, z (such as `if x == "":`), you will never reach the double checks (i.e. `if x == "" and y == ""`).

Comment: Shorter version of taking three inputs and summing non-blank inputs: `print(sum(map(lambda v: int(v) if v else 0, [input('x = '), input('y = '), input('z = ')])))`

Comment: _As you can see, this takes quite some lines. How do i simplify this?_ If you're looking for feedback on working code, then this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a null input and try to convert it to int. But instead, you can strip the string, and see if its valid. If its not, just add `0`. If it is, add the number by converting it to an int.

```py
x = input().strip()
y = input().strip()
z = input().strip()

ans = int(x if x else 0) + int(y if y else 0) + int(z if z else 0)
print(ans)
```